# Participant video rooms

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I recently tried to find a solution to fetch all active video rooms for a participant.

Server-side API does not provide any useful [filters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#get-list-filters), best I could do is fetch all the rooms that are in the status of **in-progress** and then filter them by the participant's unique name.

I also checked the JS SDK on the client side and could not find any viable solution to this problem.

I recently saw that an option to get a list of [participant conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/participant-conversation-resource#list-all-of-a-participants-conversations) has been added to the admin SDK, are there any plans to add such an option for participant video rooms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. I passed this question to the video team who recommended the workaround you have found (fetch all in-progress rooms and filter by participant name) as the best option at the moment.